# List of base profiles

Tags: python, kameleo

I have a question about profiles

Based on https://github.com/kameleo-io/local-api-examples/blob/2048fd86cbb542b465854bbccc9d5d47b27f2510/python/create_profile/app.py#L16C1-L16C14

It returns a random list of 25 profiles and I have an issue from time to time where I do not receive the necessary profile that I need created.

For example:

```
base_profiles = client.search_base_profiles(
    device_type='desktop',
    browser_product='chrome',
    os_family='windows',
    language='en-us',
```

This is where I expected to see profile.browser.major == 122 and profile.os.version == '11', but occasionally there is no v122. Do you know how I can be sure I receive it back in 100% cases for the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm writing this message, the latest version of Chrome is v123. Kameleo will return 25 base profiles randomly. The first 10 for the given filtering criteria should be the latest version if any is available (so v123), the rest are profiles randomly with a slightly older chrome version: 120, 121, 122 - you cannot force to have v122 each time. What you can do is: simply search again for new BaseProfiles until you see the one that fits your criteria.